# Trying to paint an image in java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, paintcomponent

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
Image img;
Screen screen;

GamePanel() {
    setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setBackground(new Color(100, 0, 0));

    screen = new Screen();
    screen.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
    add(screen);

    img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("monster.jpg");   
}

public void repaintScreen(){
    screen.repaint();
}

private class Screen extends JLabel{

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }   
}
```

Hello I am trying to draw an Image but it never works. I also tryed to load the image in Different ways but allways the same. But there is noch warning so something like that showing up.
But when I put it as an Icon in an JLable it works.

Comment: Why?  `JLabel` already supports displaying an image...

Comment: yes and that's why my class Screen extends from an Label

Comment: But why not just use `setIcon`?  Why do you need to paint the image yourself?

Comment: because I later have more pics and thought that would be better but maybe I am wrong

Comment: If all you want to do is show them, `JLabel` is fine, you can use `setIcon` to change the image been displayed as well, all automagically

Comment: do you know how they make it in big games with many graphics???

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022754/java-bouncing-ball/13022788#13022788) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417786/rotating-multiple-images-causing-flickering-java-graphics2d/23419824#23419824)?

Comment: ok i got my problem I need to add the package name for my source

Answer (score 0):

final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\image.png"));

Confused are you trying to draw to a JPanel/JFrame?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/

```
final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\image.png"));
GamePanel gamePanel;

 JPanel pane = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };


    gamePanel(or screen).add(pane);
}
```

Comment: i am trying to draw to an JLabel and drawRect works and drawImage doean't and I don't know why

Comment: JLabel label= new JLabel() { and   gamePanel(or screen).add(pane); ??

Comment: I add the Screen(Label) to an JPanel and Later the JPanel to an JFrame if that is your question

Comment: Lol dont use "Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("monster.jpg");" to draw an image onto screen.. Use BufferedImage preferably

Comment: @0x2B Or use `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);`

Comment: @0x2B I also prefer `ImageIO` ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Gah stop im a mess :p